# Handle Bulk data or improve the performance in wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am new to wordpress. I have created a plugin in php in this, there are three tables

```
1. Key     - id,name (abiut 5 lakh contents )
2. domain  - id,domain_name,site (abiut 1 lakh contents )
3. sdomain - id,domain,site
```

what i need is compare `key` and `domain` and move the domain details whose 
 `domain->domain_name` matches with `key->name`

```
 for($x=0;$x<=100000;$x=$x+100) { 
 $comres = $wpdb->get_results(SELECT *
 FROM `domain` as a INNER JOIN (
             SELECT name
             FROM `key` LIMIT $x,100)
             AS b ON (a.domain_name LIKE CONCAT('%', b.name, '%')) ORDER BY id");      
  //here query to insert to table sdomain 
  }
```

but its taking more time and server getting crashed. How can i solve this

Comment: From table domain All fields are required and from key its only taking name

Comment: Pagination?? why? I have used the above query within loop with limit

Comment: @Gautam3164 Not its taking more than 2 hours

Comment: @Gautam3164 Does wordpress is not a good option for this type of site means for handle bulk amount of data?

Comment: Salini it is not consider that you are using wordpress or anything else.may you have the problem in your query